# How to remove executable permssion to file created in docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mkdir

I have a project that i am working on, it involves creating a directory where files would be stored. This project runs in a docker container though am using a windows 10 machine with Docker Desktop program.
Below is the code snippet that creates the directory where the files are to be stored

```
 if (!file_exists('upload/photos/' . date('Y'))) {
    mkdir('upload/photos/' . date('Y'), 0777, true);
}
if (!file_exists('upload/photos/' . date('Y') . '/' . date('m'))) {
    mkdir('upload/photos/' . date('Y') . '/' . date('m'), 0777, true);
}
```

When the code is executed, a directory and file is successfully created both in the docker container and also on the project folder in the windows machine. But the file permissions are different for the different machines
For docker machine
[image for how the file permission is on docker machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Ycy.png)

For windows machine
[image for how the file permission is on windows machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYY4l.png)

I have tried running chmod command within the docker container but it was of no effect on the files.
How am i able to remove the executable permission on the folder created in the docker machine

[Here is also an image of my Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDLvq.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you run those images you've attached?  Can you replace those with the actual text of the Dockerfile and the error you're getting?

Comment: @DavidMaze i run then using docker compose, its just that i dont get an error. it just isnt showing the same permission for both machines

Comment: You need a YAML file to run `docker-compose`, not the PNG files you've attached here.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes i used the yaml file to run